# Dúvida sobre porque não dá nullpointexception

Tags: java

É uma dúvida besta mas por que esse código dá certo?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {


    List<String> lista2 = teste();
    System.out.println(lista2.toString());
}
```

Neste método eu devo retornar uma lista mas tem um segundo 'return null' ele não deveria ser executado também?

```
public static List<String> teste(){

    List<String> meu = new ArrayList<String>();
    meu.add("iodfsj");
    meu.add("jfgfy");
    meu.add("ophgkyp");
    meu.add("jifrl");

    if(true){
        return meu;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Qual é o objetivo do código? Por que tem esse `null` aí? Por que tem esse `if true` aí?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NullPointerException` estoura sempre que é feita uma tentativa de acessar um membro de um objeto nulo.

Perceba que `lista2` recebe o resultado de `teste()` é o resultado de `teste()` **nunca vai ser `null`**.

Isso acontece porque a execução do método **para** imediatamente no primeiro `return`.

```
public static List<String> teste(){    
    List<String> meu = new ArrayList<String>();
    meu.add("iodfsj");
    meu.add("jfgfy");
    meu.add("ophgkyp");
    meu.add("jifrl");

    if(true) { // Sempre vai entrar no bloco
        return meu; // Aqui tem um return. "meu" será retornado e a execução do método para
    }

    return null;
    // Isto só será executado quando não entrar no if. 
    // Ou seja, nunca, no código atual
}
```

Comment: Valeeeeeu! Era simplesmente isso que eu queria saber.
O motivo, agora já sei.

Answer (score 1):

Não, apenas uma instrução de `return` pode ser executada.
Uma vez que você chama o `return`, troca de contexto, saindo da função.

Comment: Entendi...um return executado por vez hein...saquei

Answer (score 1):

O `null` não está sendo executado porque seu bloco `if` sempre retorna `true`. Além disso, em java, cada instrução possui apenas um `return`.

Caso queira ainda sim retornar dois valores, você pode tentar concatena-los

Comment: valeu,  entendi. ;)